# PHP_XLSXWriter error only on Linux

Tags: php, xml, linux, excel

When using `class PHP_XLSXWriter` [LINK](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter) on Linux system I always get this error opening the file in Excel:

```
Parte rimossa: Parte /xl/sharedStrings.xml con errore XML.  (Stringhe)
(Part removed: Part /xl/sharedStrings.xml with error XML. (Strings))
Carattere xml non valido. Riga 2, colonna 1898.
(xml char not valid. Row 2, column 1898.)
Record rimossi: Informazioni cella dalla parte /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
(Record removed: cells informations from part /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml)
```

On `Windows PHP Apache` no errors, no problems! I have no idea how to solve the problem...

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: The error tells that there is a not valid character in `/xl/sharedStrings.xml`. This means a character which is not UTF-8 encoded but in some ISO encoding for example. Use UTF-8 encoding everywhere to avoid such pain. In PHP source code, in DB, as default charset for apache, everywhere.

Comment: please edit your question and add a minimum valid XML snippet. And you should definitely take a look at the character in row 2, col 1898 ;-)

Comment: I found the problem... Is not on xls class, but on database connection. I use DB2 PDO ODBC and the problem is that on Windows all is working fine but in Linux for some strange reasons the behavior of the driver is different...